# iOS 11 - always opens photo library even the source type change it from .photoLibrary to .camera

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios11, xcode9-beta

The code is perfectly working in iOS 10 and below. But, in iOS 11 after  cancel the photo library and open the camera its always opens the photo library. This is only happening in iOS 11.

Code is compiled in **Xcode 9 Beta 4**.

**Code below:**

```
@IBAction func buttonProfilePicPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openCamera()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openGallary()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    imgPicker.delegate = self
    self.present(imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func openCamera()
{
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
    {
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imgPicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func openGallary()
{
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It is still happening to me. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func startCameraFromViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, withDelegate delegate:
        UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate) -> Void {

        if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) == false) {
            print("fail")
        }

        let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraController.sourceType = .camera
        cameraController.allowsEditing = true
        cameraController.delegate = delegate

        present(cameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

This is the code that works for me. Same problem on iOS 11, but working with this. Maybe you need to remove `self.present(imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)` in `buttonProfilePicPressed` method.

Comment: Both your and #Vladimir answers are correct. I take your answer as accepted because you are answered first. Also your reputation is in initial stage.

Answer (score 5):

I found what's wrong.

**MAIN: You must set sourceType before you present UIImagePickerController.** About this you can read in documentation [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller).

Yes, you can see documentation for [sourceType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619167-sourcetype), but information about sourceType on documentation page is wrong or not actual for iOS 11.

*In result:*

1. Firstly you must configure UIImagePickerController
2. Secondly present it.

in your case you need remove only one row:

```
@IBAction func buttonProfilePicPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    ...
    self.present(imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil) //REMOVE IT!!!!!111
}
```

P.S. Checked and work on Xcode 9 GM

Comment: Both your and #gile87 answers are correct. I take #gile87 answer as accepted because he is answered first. Also his reputation is in initial stage.